# react-native Gradlew doesn't create app.aab

Tags: typescript, react-native

## System Info

1. react-native: 0.59.8
2. android-studio: 3.3.1

## Background

I'm making simple react-native app.
I tried to upload my application on Google Play Store, but failed.
I followed [this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android). As it said, I typed `./gradlew buildRelease` on terminal. It results below.

```
> Configure project :react-native-voice
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
info Writing bundle output to:, /Users/mac88/Desktop/Projects/voice-car-v2/NativeApp/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
info Done writing bundle output
info Copying 13 asset files
info Done copying assets

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/mac88/Desktop/Projects/voice-car-v2/NativeApp/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 29s
63 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 53 up-to-date
```

## Problem

Yes, it show `BUILD SUCCESSFULL in 29s`! but there is no `android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab` or in any folder.

How to get `app.aab` file?

Comment: check here `android/app/build/outputs/apk/release`
you can see `app-release.apk` there is generate succeed

Comment: @HardikVirani OMG, I refresh VSCode and it appeared now ! Thank you :D

Comment: But the original question was about ".aab" file, not ".apk"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you generate android apk using `./gradlew buildRelease` it automatically save in your project `android/app/build/outputs/apk/release` folder you can find `app-release.apk` if apk is generate successfully.

Another option is when you generate apk using `android studio` it give you options to save your apk in selected folder or directories.

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

If you're trying to create a *.aab you need to use `bundleRelease` not `buildRelease` That will create the .aab as you are expecting.

Comment: This is a more helpful answer because the solution doesn't suggest using an additional too like android studio for example but only fixes the command to be executed in the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `./gradlew bundleRelease`.

After the process, go to `YOUR APP NAME/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release`.

Comment: CD to android directory before starting the above steps